# Could not instantiate mail function PhPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am having problems with my Phpmailer. For some reason it says Could not instantiate mail function. Could it be because of the From and Fromname? I have little to no experience in PhpMailer so it would be great if someone can help me!

```
<?php ob_start();
$naam= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["nome"]);
$telefoon= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["telefone"]);
$email= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["email"]);
$woonplaats= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["cidade"]);
$lengte= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["altura"]);
$gewicht= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["peso"]);
$streefgewicht= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["ideal"]);
$leeftijd= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["idade"]);
$hoe= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["amigo"]);
$kanaal= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["canal"]);
$commentaar= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["comentario"]);
$waarover= htmlspecialchars ($_REQUEST["escolha"]);
//echo"$naam $telefoon $email $lengte $gewicht $streefgewicht $leeftijd $hoe $kanaal $commentaar        $waarover";
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$naamgeadresseerde = "Karin Klaver";
$emailadres = "info@proefpakket4you.nl";

//verstuur nieuwsbrief
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Geef aan dat het een HTML mail betreft
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->From = $emailadres;
$mail->FromName = $naamgeadresseerde;

$mail->AddAddress("$emailadres","$naamgeadresseerde");
$mail->AddCC("info@shapecare.nl", "K. Klaver");
$mail->AddBCC("mikfetter@gmail.com", "Mik Fetter");

$mail->Subject = "Reactie proefpakket4you.nl"; // Subject aanpassen

// Alternatieve body
$mail->AltBody = "Reactie proefpakket4you.nl";

$mail->Body = "
Naam: $naam <br>
Telefoonnummer: $telefoon <br>
E-mail: $email <br>
Lengte: $lengte <br>
Gewicht: $gewicht <br>
Streefgewicht: $streefgewicht <br>
Leeftijd: $leeftijd <br>
Hoe op deze site terechtgekomen (kennis): $hoe <br>
Hoe op deze site terechtgekomen: $kanaal <br>
Aanvullende opmerkingen: $commentaar <br>
Meer info/ Proberen / Starten: $waarover<br>

";

//$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo 'Er ging iets mis tijdens het versturen';
echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else
        {
//vervolgstap zetten
echo"Goed gedaan";
header ("Location: http://www.proefpakket4you.nl/bedankt.php?naam=$naam");
        }

?>
```

Comment: Could you show us the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be because your server doesn't have a mail server installed or configured, or that your php.ini setting for `sendmail_path` is wrong.

On a command line, can you send a message like this:

```
echo 'test' | mail -s 'test' me@example.com
```

If that doesn't work, php's mail function won't either.

If your sendmail path is wrong, you can either fix your ini file or switch to `IsSendmail()` and provide the path in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the option:

```
$phpmailer->IsSMTP();
```

made it more reliable for me.

Also it would be cleaner if you just used:

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

with $body as the html string instead of:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "
Naam: $naam <br>
Telefoonnummer: $telefoon <br>
E-mail: $email <br>
Lengte: $lengte <br>
Gewicht: $gewicht <br>
Streefgewicht: $streefgewicht <br>
Leeftijd: $leeftijd <br>
Hoe op deze site terechtgekomen (kennis): $hoe <br>
Hoe op deze site terechtgekomen: $kanaal <br>
Aanvullende opmerkingen: $commentaar <br>
Meer info/ Proberen / Starten: $waarover<br>";
```

also you can set From using (shouldn't need "quotes"):

```
$mail->setFrom($emailadres, $naamgeadresseerde);
```

Are you sending using a local mail server or a specific server?
If you you would need something like:

```
$mail->Host  = '127.0.0.1';
$mail->Port = 25;
```

for local host, or if sending through another server you might be required to provide login details to send using that email address, e.g:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host  = 'smtp.microsoft365.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
```

Or it could also be what @Synchro said, and that you haven't set up a mail server on your computer....